# MongoDb Not in comparing two collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Lets say i have two collections

The Family Collection

```
{"Name":"Steven", "Children":[{"Name":"Liv", "Children":[{"Name":"Milo"}] },{"Name":"Mia"},{"Name":"Chelsea"}]}
```

And the movie collection

```
{"Movie":"Rush Hour 3", "Actors":["Jackie","Mia"]}
{"Movie":"LOTR", "Actors":["Viggo","Liv"]}
```

Now i need a query to find the names of the family members that's not actors. The result should contain Steven, Milo and Chelsea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do this "yourself" in your application logic.  Mongo doesnt do joins.  So essentially, your current collections are structured similar to relational independent tables -- in mongo, you would have to redesign your schema so that your query is possible (or , like I said, do it in the app)